# Datos de SQL Server a BigQuery a través de ETL Dataflow

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

la idea es crear un ETL en Dataflow y a través de un "archivo csv" crear el job para traer una tabla desde SQL Server. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? Entiendo que primero tengo que crear un bucket en Cloud Storage, y de esta manera cargar el csv ahí para que lo lea Dataflow, y de ahí pasarlo a BigQuery. Pero, ¿qué comando debo usar en CloudShell para poder hacer la conexión a SQL Server y crear el csv en CloudStorage de la tabla que elijo en SQL Server y continuar con el proceso en Dataflow? ¿Cuál sería la mejor práctica para lograr esto?

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de que sea el mejor camino para lo que tratas de diseñar (ni que esta respuesta llega a timepo).
Pero usar Airflow puede ser la solución para crear un puente directo entre tu SQL database y Bigquery, desde esa tabla crear un Job de Dataflow (o desde el SQL Workspace de Dataflow) y realizar las transformaciones necesarias. En este escenario no hay csv.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/373527)